# Why is margin property not working in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The problem: I would like to have the page show `100%` of its content without scrolling. Currently, that's not the case.

Inside my `section` class, I included the properties `position: relative & min-height: 100vh`. When I change the min-height to height, my problem seems to be fixed. However, I have also included a `@media(max-width: 991px)`, and everything looks very much different after adjusting this one property of `height`.

For instance, my `content` class should have a `margin-top` of `100px`. However, the `margin-top` is not being applied and the content is just up there at the very top of my page.

I guess what I really want to know is why everything is working fine when I leave it as `min-height`, but everything changes when I change it to 'height'. Why is the margin-top suddenly not being applied?

I hope I explained it clearly. I have included my source code below. Thanks in advance!

[image: Current State]

```js
function imgSlider(image) {
  document.querySelector(".starbucks").src = image;
}

function circleColor(color) {
  let circle = document.querySelector(".circle")
  circle.style.background = color;
}

function toggleMenu() {
  let menu = document.querySelector('.toggle');
  let navigation = document.querySelector('.navigation');
  menu.classList.toggle('active');
  navigation.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 100px;
}

header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 20px 100px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

header .logo {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 80px;
}

header ul {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

header ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

header ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #333;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-left: 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.content .textBox {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 550px;
}

.content .textBox h2 {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 3.5em;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.4em;
}

.content .textBox h2 span {
  color: #017143;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 1000;
}

.content .textBox p {
  color: #333;
}

.content .textBox a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  background-color: #017143;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.content .imgBox {
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 600px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.content .imgBox img {
  max-width: 320px;
}

.thumb {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 20px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: flex;
}

.thumb li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.thumb li:hover {
  transform: translateY(-15px);
}

.thumb li img {
  max-width: 60px;
}

.sci {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 30px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.sci li {
  list-style: none;
}

.sci li a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px 0;
  transform: scale(0.6);
  filter: invert(1);
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: #017143;
  clip-path: circle(600px at 100% 800px);
}

@media(max-width: 991px) {
  header {
    padding: 20px;
  }
  header .logo {
    max-width: 60px;
  }
  .toggle {
    position: relative;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: url('images/menu.png');
    background-size: 30px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    filter: invert(1);
    z-index: 3;
  }
  .toggle.active {
    position: fixed;
    right: 20px;
    background: url('images/close.png');
    background-size: 25px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
  }
  .navigation {
    display: none;
  }
  .navigation.active {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  header ul li a {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin: 5px 0;
  }
  section {
    padding: 20px 20px 120px;
  }
  .content {
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-top: 100px;
  }
  .content .textBox {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .content .textBox h2 {
    font-size: 2.5em;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
  .content .imgBox {
    max-width: 100%;
    padding-right: 0px;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .content .imgBox img {
    max-width: 300px;
  }
  .circle {
    clip-path: circle(400px at center bottom);
  }
  .thumb li img {
    max-width: 50px;
  }
  .sci {
    right: 0px;
    background: #017143;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    width: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <header>
      <a href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" class="logo"></a>
      <div class="toggle" onclick="toggleMenu()"></div>
      <ul class="navigation">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">What's New</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </header>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="textBox">
        <h2>It's not just Coffee <br>It's <span>Starbucks</span></h2>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
        <a href="#">Learn More</a>
      </div>
      <div class="imgBox">
        <img src="images/img1.png" class="starbucks">
      </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="thumb">
      <li><img src="images/thumb1.png" onclick="imgSlider('images/img1.png'); circleColor('#017143')"></li>
      <li><img src="images/thumb2.png" onclick="imgSlider('images/img2.png'); circleColor('#eb7495')"></li>
      <li><img src="images/thumb3.png" onclick="imgSlider('images/img3.png'); circleColor('#d752b1')"></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="sci">
      <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/facebook.png"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/twitter.png"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/instagram.png"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: Don't use single quotes (`' '`) to highlight a code block. Use backticks ( ***` `*** ) instead.

Comment: Can you add an image of the problem because I am not able to reproduce it!

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal I have added an image, thanks for your help!

Comment: The margin appears to work correctly in the code you have provided. Could you try to narrow down the problem to a single clear example of the issue?

Comment: @DBS Sure, so basically: In the image I included in this post, not everything fits on the view height. I don't want to be able to scroll, everything should fit in the view height.

I have included the property `min-height: 100vh` inside the section class. But apparently, some elements cause my view to be larger than 100vh. On the other hand, If I change the `min-height` property to simply `height: 100vh`, my problem is fixed for the desktop version. But for smaller screen sizes (`@media(max-width: 991px)`, my view is suddently different and I have to change a lot of styling again.

Comment: @DBS What I want to know is: Why does this happen? What causes all these issues when I simply change the min-height property to height? I just want to have everything on one page without scrolling. Is that not possible without min-height set to 100vh?